# Does anyone know what bug this is?

Tags: health, bugs

I have found these bugs around my house on walls and 2 of them in my bed on separate occasions, i have been told they are not bed bugs as they are bigger and have wings but not seen them fly, they have also bitten me and its like a mosquito bite but itches a few days after still please i need some advice, i have some exterminators coming tomorrow [image]

Comment: Will the exterminators know, being in the trade and able to see them close up?

Comment: @WeatherVane i hope so! As i have a new born baby been in my home for over 5 years and 1 month ago got a new bed and mattress… i was just hoping if someone could advice me on anything as i have huge mite marks, looks like mosquito bites but slightly bigger and very itchy a day after

Comment: If the house is being fumigated, then you might like to take advice as to how soon it is safe to return there. Have you read articles such as [Is Pest Control Safe?](https://staysafe.org/pest-control/is-pest-control-safe) What has the company advised?

Comment: @WeatherVane nothing yet they are just coming to see what they are and to check for infestation etc that is why i wanted to know beforehand so they dont lie to me etcetc not sure just very nervous as i dont want my baby or myself to get bitten tonight, i have washed all beddings and checked everywhere for more and not found any more and no black spots or anything so this is wierd as i am also the only one getting bitten

Comment: Looks like a weevil of some sort, probably come in from outside. My first thought was vine weevil when I saw it, but it's too skinny.

Comment: @Separatrix and do those bite humans? Because these i found bite me and leave a swollen big lump that itches for a few days, found one in side my trousers bit my leg

Comment: @Daniella, no weevils are basically plant pests. Did you see it bite you or was it just nearby after you got bitten? Judge it by its speed of movement, most things that are after you are quick, things that are after plants only have to move faster than a plant.

Comment: @Separatrix i didnt see it actually bite me but it was the only thing inside my leggings when gone bitten and found one in my bed also, its just so frustrating … now waiting for the pest control to come

Comment: What did the exterminators tell you?